# Branch.io links Facebook issue

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I implemented branch.io links and it is working fine for WhatsApp and from Notes, but not Facebook Messenger or any other place with in-app browser.

As per [documentation](https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/universal-links/#apps-that-work-sometimes):

> To work around this limitation, your links must have deepviews or something similar enabled, with a call-to-action link/button that has a Universal Link behind it. This way, clicking a link from the app feed will open a webview containing your deepview page, and the user can then click the link/button to launch your app.

For example Facebook Messenger should open in-app browser with deepview of my link, and if user tap button - my app should be opened, it is fine for me, but doesn't work like this.

In my case facebook is opening in-app browser with my deepview and automatically (I didn't tap button) redirects me to... AppStore :(. But if I open my app manually, I'm getting callback and app is redirecting me to proper place.

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to use forced redirections for links shared on Facebook since Universal Links work conditionally. You can force Facebook to open your app by appending **$uri_redirect_mode=2** as a query parameter to your Branch link.

eg: https://example.app.link/83jlowd0?$uri_redirect_mode=2

You can learn more about forced redirections here- https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#forced-redirections

If you still face issues, please write to support@branch.io and someone from the Branch team will be able to assist you with this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. the branch object returned from Branch.io SDK was returning an object without all parameters.
All I did was follow the great document provided by Branch.io
[document provided by Branch.io](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration)

So as I was using the Scene in my app. Calling these methods in my sceneDelegate solved the issue.

```
import UIKit
import Branch
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
      // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
      // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
      // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
      guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
              // workaround for SceneDelegate continueUserActivity not getting called on cold start
        if let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first {
            
            BranchScene.shared().scene(scene, continue: userActivity)
        }
  }
  func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
      // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
      // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
      // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
      // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
  }
  func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
      // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
      // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
  }
  func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
      // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
      // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
  }
  func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
      // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
      // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
  }
  func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
      // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
      // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
      // to restore the scene back to its current state.
  }
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        BranchScene.shared().scene(scene, continue: userActivity)
  }
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        BranchScene.shared().scene(scene, openURLContexts: URLContexts)
  }
}
```